# Django creates an extra object on submit

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an Answer object once the page is rendered, when the user provide his input, the Answer object should be updated with the new input and saved. I am able to do that but for some reason an extra object is created when the user clicks the submit button and that object is always None. I use AJAX to send data from the template.

views.py

```
def attention_view(request):
    participant = get_object_or_404(Participant, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        question_id = request.POST.get('assigned_question')
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        answer = Answer.objects.get(participant=participant, question=question)

        if answer.answer is not None: 
            #preventing participants from changing their answer
            HttpResponse('')

        else:

            answer.answer = selected_choice
            answer.save()

    attention_question = Question.objects.get(id=13)
    answer = Answer.objects.create(participant=participant, question=attention_question)
    context = {'attention_question': attention_question, 'answer': answer}
    return render(request, 'study/AttentionCheck.html', context)
```

what could be the cause of creating an extra object ?

Comment: You mention that you use Ajax, it might be a javascript issue. Are you sure that you send the request only once?

Comment: yes I am sure, I do send another AJAX request whilst the page is running but it goes to another view and does something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is (simplified):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if answer.answer is not None: 
            # HttpResponse created and freed right away
            pass
        else:
            answer.answer = selected_choice
            answer.save()

    answer = Answer.objects.create(participant=participant,
      question=attention_question)

    return render(request, 'study/AttentionCheck.html', context)
```

Notice that 1) you always call `Answer.objects.create` 2) always return the rendered AttentionCheck.html.

I also noticed that you are dealing with two different questions here: the question with an `id` given by POST and the one with an `id` of 13.

Depending on your exact requirements, I think this should be the solution:

```
def attention_view(request):
    participant = get_object_or_404(Participant, user=request.user)

    question = FIXME_WHICH_QUESTION

    answer, created = Answer.objects.get_or_create(participant=participant,
        question=question)

    if request.method == 'POST' and answer.answer is None: 
        answer.answer = selected_choice
        answer.save()

    context = {'attention_question': question, 'answer': answer}
    return render(request, 'study/AttentionCheck.html', context)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment about the question, I have fixed that now. I tried your suggestion but I got an error: study.models.Answer.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Answer -- it returned 2!

Comment: Makes sense, since you have all these duplicated objects in your database. You'll want to clean up the duplicates in the Django shell first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/